# Drupal 8 - Variables - Template Twig - Cache

Tags: theming, 8, caching

In the HOOK of my project XXX_preprocess I am defining a variable based on a cookie.

My Hook function

```
function XXXXXX_preprocess(array &$variables) {
if (isset($_COOKIE[personsSearchCookie]) && !empty($_COOKIE[personsSearchCookie])) {
    $personsFilter = explode("-", $_COOKIE[personsSearchCookie]);
    $variables["personsFilter"] = array (
        "filterType" => $personsFilter[0],
        "filterId" => $personsFilter[1]
    );
}
```

But in the Twig template, it always gives me the initial value of that variable, it never changes.
My Twig code:

```
Filtering results by [{{ personsFilter.filterType }}]<br />

{% if personsFilter is defined and personsFilter.filterType is defined and personsFilter.filterType is not empty %}
    {% if personsFilter.filterType == "area" %}
        Filtering by Area <br />      
    {% endif %}

    {% if personsFilter.filterType == "office" %}
        Filtering by Office <br />
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    No filtering
{% endif %}
```

This should be a cache theme, right?

How can I make so that when my cookie changes, the variable is modified and since twig can access the new value?

In the prepreocess function in all re-loads, the variable change correctly, but, in twig, the variable have bad value.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the answer here are cache contexts based on cookie name needing to be added. But I am not experienced enough with them yet. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts

Answer (score 3):

In your question, it wasn't clear how you are defining the render array (a block, a form, etc.) Assuming you are rendering this twig file through a render array, you could add the following to the render array for this particular element to turn off caching of this element:

```
 '#cache' => [
    'max-age' => 0,
  ],
```

You could get more specific by implementing conditional logic to clear the cache on a certain condition. From the `examples` module, in the cache_example, we have the CacheExampleForm function createExpiringItem():

```
/**
* Submit handler to create a new cache item with specified expiration.
*/
public function createExpiringItem($form, &$form_state) {

$tags = array(
  'cache_example:1',
);

$interval = $form_state->getValue('expiration');
if ($interval == 'never_remove') {
  $expiration = CacheBackendInterface::CACHE_PERMANENT;
  $expiration_friendly = $this->t('Never expires');
}
else {
  $expiration = time() + $interval;
  $expiration_friendly = format_date($expiration);
}
// Set the expiration to the actual Unix timestamp of the end of the
// required interval. Also add a tag to it to be able to clear caches more
// precise.
$this->cacheBackend->set('cache_example_expiring_item', $expiration_friendly, $expiration, $tags);
drupal_set_message($this->t('cache_example_expiring_item was set to expire at %time', array('%time' => $expiration_friendly)));
}
```

And, also shown in the examples is invalidating:

```
$tags = array(
  'cache_example:1',
);
Cache::invalidateTags($tags);
```

So in your preprocess, you could use this type of logic to invalidate the cache. Hope this helps.