# Node template suggestion based on date field

Tags: theming, 9

I am trying to get different templates for events node based on the date of the event. The content type used will be same for both, ie. Event.

**This is what I have done so far:**
Created a content type: Event
Added a date range field: field_date

**This is what I need to get:**
If the date of the event is greater than the current date, template suggestion will be   *node--upcoming.html.twig*
If the date of the event is less than the current date, template suggestion will be *node--past.html.twig*

I tried with the following code:

```
function strive_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
  
  if ($node->getType() === 'event') {
    $date = $node->field_date->end_value ?? $node->field_date->start_value;
    $current_date = new \DateTime();
    $date = new \DateTime($date);
    $node_type_suggestion = $current_date > $date ? 'past' : 'upcoming';
    $suggestions[] = 'node__' . $node_type_suggestion;
  }
}
```

Doing this, I am getting **node--upcoming.html.twig** for all the event nodes.

[image]

Comment: This isn't the best way to handle this. Even if you were to get your template suggestions working I think the template would be cached so you wouldn't see the template change without the twig/theming cache being cleared. Sounds more like you'd need a custom block/controller with a max-age e.g. 1hour or something

Comment: @unusedspoon I agree, I would calculate an `isPast` boolean in a preprocess and utilize it within the node template. Concerning the caching you can get around that using the following answer as an example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/243788/20866